# grouping records in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am building a simple blog app and I want to add an archive were people can click on a month and all articles in that month are displayed. It's like grouping based on the month and year. For example,

**Articles:**

- june 2012
- may 2011

So when clicking on a date it takes you to a page and lists all the articles of that month. How can I get it done?

Answer (score 1):

For July 2012:

```
require 'date'

month = 7
year = 2012

start_date = Date.new(year,month,1)
end_date =  Date.new(year,month+1,1) - 1.day

articles_in_july = Article.where(:created_at => start_date..end_date)
```

You can test in a console with the above. However, in your model you probably want:

```
def self.in_month(month,year)
    start_date = Date.new(year,month,1)
    end_date =  Date.new(year,month+1,1) - 1.day
    where(:created_at => start_date..end_date)
end
```

Then you can call:

```
Article.in_month(7,2012)
```

or, assuming a User has_many articles:

```
current_user.articles.in_month(7,2012)
```

Comment: You can also do this: `date =  Date.new(year,month,1)` and then `where(:created_at => date..date.end_of_month)`. Makes it a bit shorter.

Comment: The answer is good but how can I pass the month and the year in the link assuming that the list items are in a link tag. And how will the route look like. I have been trying to do this for almost a whole day now and still cannot pass the month and year into a parameter.

Comment: @mischa your answer made my work a lot easier to impliment. Thanks.